# Align and reshape polygons based on surrounding polylines

Tags: qgis, arcpy, arcmap, pyqgis, alignment

I am trying to use a shapefile with polygons and I am trying to align it to a road network, that the polygons align themselves to surrounding streets. Is there a way to automatize alignments between nodes of the polygons and polylines or sometime similar?

Comment: You have tags for QGIS and ArcMap but which would you prefer to use to try and do this?

Comment: Can you post a picture of a typical polygon/line situation please?

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS...

Let's say you have polygons and lines such as in the example below:

[image]

Perform a [feature to line](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000039000000), with the polygons and the lines as your input. This slices the polygons by the lines.

[image]

Select all the features on one side of the line.

[image]

Export selected features.

[image]

Turn off all layers except the new layer.

[image]

Select the 'slivers'.

[image]

Perform an [Eliminate](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00130000003s000000.htm).

[image]

Now do the same for the other side of the line and merge your results, along with any other polygons from your original polygon feature class that weren't included in the geoprocessing.